# How to open XML file with EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I try to open an Excel file with the XML extension with EPPlus library.

```
using (var p = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo("file.xml")))
```

I can open the file with Excel manually. 
With the Excel Interop  library it works too, but I would like to test performance with other library.

I took a look to the source of EPPlus and I see, it try to create an ZipPackage. But Xml file can't be transform to ZIP ... It contains already all information.

Someone success to open that kind of file with EPPlus ?

Comment: Why EPPlus and XML? there are a lot easier ways to work with XML in C#

Comment: The XML template file is created for use with Excel. (This is a file provided by a third party service)
But it's true, if I work directly with XML tools, it should work.
I will test. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Microsoft Excel can open many formats (including XML, CSV, TSV, etc.) and OpenXML happened to be a primary file format it produces as output. EPPlus is specifically designed to work with OpenXML format. And Excel' ability to open other formats does not translate into those formats compatible with OpenXML. So I highly doubt that EPPlus will help you with XML.